# concatenate strings separated by a comma

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, concatenation

How can I get a string from database and concat it with another string seperated by a comma

If I have a string such as this "2, 3" in the database. I am getting the string from:

```
$item->options
```

Now I have an array which I convert into a string seperated by commas like this:

```
implode(',', $request->options);
```

Now my question is how can I put those two strings together seperated by a comma? I tried using `+` but it is adding the strings together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $item->options . ',' . implode(',', $request->options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You concatenate in PHP using the period `.`; if you want to concatenate $string1 and $string2 separated by a comma, it would be

```
$concatenated_string = $string1 . ',' . $string2;
```